# How to group a list of paths by their parent?

Tags: python, path

I have a list of paths and I want them to dynamically separate into lists they should belong to based on the folder name they come from. First two come from *"tent1"* folder and I want them together in one list and so on. I don't want to hardcode the names of those folders and then append paths to them. For example:

```
paths = [
    '/var/lib/cons/states/tent1/tops-ok_2022_11_28', 
    '/var/lib/cons/states/tent1/tops-ok_2022_11_27',  
    '/var/lib/cons/states/tent2/tops-ok_2022_11_28', 
    '/var/lib/cons/states/tent2/tops-ok_2022_11_27', 
    '/var/lib/cons/states/tent3/tops-ok_2022_11_28', 
    '/var/lib/cons/states/tent3/tops-ok_2022_11_27', 
    '/var/lib/cons/states/tent4/tops-ok_2022_11_28', 
    '/var/lib/cons/states/tent4/tops-ok_2022_11_27',
    ]
```

and I want them to be like this:

```
[['/var/lib/cons/states/tent1/tops-ok_2022_11_28', 
  '/var/lib/cons/states/tent1/tops-ok_2022_11_27'], 
 ['/var/lib/cons/states/tent2/tops-ok_2022_11_28', 
  '/var/lib/cons/states/tent2/tops-ok_2022_11_27'],
 ['/var/lib/cons/states/tent3/tops-ok_2022_11_28', 
  '/var/lib/cons/states/tent3/tops-ok_2022_11_27'],
 ['/var/lib/cons/states/tent4/tops-ok_2022_11_28', 
  '/var/lib/cons/states/tent4/tops-ok_2022_11_27']]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your input is sorted by path (i.e. the same paths are sequential), you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from os.path import dirname

out = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(paths, dirname)]
```

If the paths are not sorted, you can use a dictionary as intermediate:

```
out = {}
for p in paths:
    (out.setdefault(dirname(p), [])
        .append(p)
    )
    
out = list(out.values())
```

Output:

```
[['/var/lib/cons/states/tent1/tops-ok_2022_11_28',
  '/var/lib/cons/states/tent1/tops-ok_2022_11_27'],
 ['/var/lib/cons/states/tent2/tops-ok_2022_11_28',
  '/var/lib/cons/states/tent2/tops-ok_2022_11_27'],
 ['/var/lib/cons/states/tent3/tops-ok_2022_11_28',
  '/var/lib/cons/states/tent3/tops-ok_2022_11_27'],
 ['/var/lib/cons/states/tent4/tops-ok_2022_11_28',
  '/var/lib/cons/states/tent4/tops-ok_2022_11_27']]
```

##### alternative with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from itertools import groupby
from pathlib import Path

out = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(paths, lambda x: Path(x).parent)]
```